# width in caption package does not react on \linewidth

Tags: captions, packages

I observed, that the current version of the [caption package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) does not react correctly on `width=0.9\linewidth` or `width=0.9\columnwidth`.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width = .9\linewidth, font = small, labelfont = bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a long figure caption, to show the problem with the width option and variable length like columnwidth and linewidth}
    \label{figlabel}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Currently, I use the option `minmargin = 0.05\linewidth` instead of `width=...`.

Comment: In the preamble, \linewidth=8191.99998pt.  At begin document, \linewidth=418.25555pt.  Otherwise, it works fine.

Comment: That´s interessting. Why does `minmargin=.05\linewidth` work?

Comment: `margin=.05\linewidth` does not work here since this sets the caption margin immediately to a fixed value. It was implemented this way to provide backward compatibility to versions 1 + 2 of the `caption` package. When using `minmargin` the value will not be set immediately but when used instead. It was implemented this way to provide compatibility to the AMS document classes. So in the end this is confusing,sacrificing consistency because of compatibility reasons. (But I introduced `calcmargin` and `calcwidth` in v3.2,they behave similar to `minmargin`,i.e. calculating the value when needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caption package option `width` calculates the width of the caption immediately. So when writing `\captionsetup{width=.9\linewidth}` the result is dependent on the value of `\linewidth` at this point, and will not change during the document.

(And as John Kormylo has already commented, \linewidth is not set properly yet within the preamble.)

But one can use `calcwidth` instead which recalculates `.9\linewidth` every time a caption width is needed:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[calcwidth = .9\linewidth, font = small, labelfont = bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a long figure caption, to show the problem with the width option and variable length like columnwidth and linewidth}
    \label{figlabel}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

If the goal is having a caption width which fits the figure width, one can use `\captionbox` instead:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font = small, labelfont = bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionbox
      {This is a long figure caption, to show the problem with the width option and variable length like columnwidth and linewidth\label{figlabel}}
      {\includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

`calcwidth` and `\captionbox` were introduced in version 3.2 (2011/07/30) of the `caption` package but unfortunately they are not mentioned in the documentation yet, only in the changelog [¹]. (Currently I'm updating the documentation but progress is slow.)

To get an idea how `\captionbox` works take a look at the `subcaption` documentation. `\subcaptionbox` is described there, and `\subcaptionbox` behaves very similar to `\captionbox`, the first for typesetting content for sub-figures and sub-tables, the second one for typesetting content for figures and tables.

[1] http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/CHANGELOG

Comment: `calcwidth` is exactly what I am looking for. Do you know what´s the star variant for?

Comment: It seems that I've implemented `calcwidth*` because `width*` exists. And `width*` exists since this was part of experimental code which allowed to set both, margin and caption. So in short `width*` and `calcwidth*` are just crap, forget about them, should remove that in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a conflict between the `caption` package and `koomascript`, which has its own tools to format captions. If you want the caption width to be equal to the figure width, you can use the `measuredfigure` environment from `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is a long figure caption, to show the problem with the width option and variable length like columnwidth and linewidth}
  \label{figlabel}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{measuredfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a long figure caption, to show the problem with the width option and variable length like columnwidth and linewidth}
    \label{figlabel}
  \end{measuredfigure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, the problem is not a conflict between `caption` and KOMA-Script, you'll have the same problem when using a different document class. The problem is that `\linewidth` is not set to a proper value when `width=.9\linewidth` is calculated.

Comment: @Axel Sommerfeldt: With KOMA-Script,  the caption on my system overflows into both margins. Using the article class, it is two-lined within the page margins. So I think there's a problem, maybe due to the `width=0.9\linewidth`.

Comment: So it seems article is setting `\linewidth` to a proper value immediately but KOMA-Script does this later on, i.e. `\AtBeginDocument`. However I think using `width=..\linewidth` in the preamble is a bad idea since `\linewidth` can change, e.g. within a `wrapfigure`.

Comment: Yes. That's why I think `measuredfigure` is  probably the best solution.the

Comment: IMHO this depends on the packages already used. If the author is using the `caption` package anyway, using `calcwidth` (or `calcmargin`) or `\captionbox` looks like a good option for me. If the author is not using the `caption` package using `threeparttable` is (of course) a good alternative solution.