# Two tikzpictures in minipages have overlapped caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, minipage

I'm trying to put two tikzpictures in two minipages, but their caption are overlapped. Here the code I'm using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.50cm,left=3.00cm,right=3.00cm]{geometry}


 \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,commath}
    \usepackage{caption}    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
  
\captionsetup {
       format=plain,
       width=0.80\textwidth,
       font=normal, 
       labelfont=bf,
       figurename = Fig. ,
       tablename = Tab.
    }

    \title{\Huge{\textbf{Test}}}
    \author{me}
    \date{}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{figure}
\centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \centering
                \draw [<->,thick] (0,2.8) node (yaxis) [left] {$t$}
                    |- (2.8,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
                \draw[thick]
                    (0,0) -- (0,-2.8)
                    (0,0) -- (-2.8,0);
                \draw[green, ultra thick] (0,-2.90) -- (0,2.90);
                \draw[dashed] 
                    (0,2.90) -- (0,2.95)
                    (0,-2.90) -- (0,-2.95);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof{figure}{Worldline of a static point-like source}
            \label{fig:static_source}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw [<->,thick] (0,2.8) node (yaxis) [left] {$t$}
                    |- (2.8,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
                \draw[thick]
                    (0,0) -- (0,-2.8)
                    (0,0) -- (-2.8,0);
                \node[mark size = 3pt, green] at (0,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
                \draw[dashed] 
                    (0,2.90) -- (0,2.95)
                    (0,-2.90) -- (0,-2.95);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof{figure}{Worldline of an instantaneous point-like source}
            \label{fig:inst_source}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    
    \end{document}
```

Can someone help me? I see that without the caption setup it works good.

Comment: The problem is that the width is set immediately using the current value of of \textwidth.  If you use [width=0.32\textwidth] or reset the width every time \textwidth changes, you will get the desired effect.

Comment: (i) Remove line `width=0.80\linewidth` from caption setup. (ii) remove `\centering` from inside of `tikzpicture` (it's no harm, nor it has any benefit) and insert `\hfil` between `minipage`s .

Comment: Maybe this one helps here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280822/width-in-caption-package-does-not-react-on-linewidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As I mentioned in comment, problem is your caption set up. If you like to have, that the caption width id 0.8 width of environment, where it is, than the width you need to setup in this environment.
- In your case you not need to use `\captionof` since captions are inside `figure` float.
- Remove command `\centering` inside of `tikzpicture` (it's no harm, nor it has any benefit)
- Using `\hfill` between `minipage`s will push them apart so that all horisontal spaces around them will be equal.

A possible MWE (in which I removed everything that has nothing to do with your problem) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin=3cm, vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup{ format=plain,
               labelfont=bf,
               figurename = Fig. ,
               tablename = Tab.}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [<->,thick] (0,2.8) node (yaxis) [left] {$t$}
                |- (2.8,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
            \draw[thick]
                (0,0) -- (0,-2.8)
                (0,0) -- (-2.8,0);
            \draw[green, ultra thick] (0,-2.90) -- (0,2.90);
            \draw[dashed]
                (0,2.90) -- (0,2.95)
                (0,-2.90) -- (0,-2.95);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionsetup{width=0.80\textwidth}
        \caption{Worldline of a static point-like source}
        \label{fig:static_source}
    \end{minipage}\hfil
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [<->,thick] (0,2.8) node (yaxis) [left] {$t$}
                |- (2.8,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
            \draw[thick]
                (0,0) -- (0,-2.8)
                (0,0) -- (-2.8,0);
            \node[mark size = 3pt, green] at (0,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
            \draw[dashed]
                (0,2.90) -- (0,2.95)
                (0,-2.90) -- (0,-2.95);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionsetup{width=0.80\textwidth}
        \caption{Worldline of an instantaneous point-like source}
        \label{fig:inst_source}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Just introduce `\hspace{2pc}` tag will add more horizontal space between the images, and the `MWE` is:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.50cm,left=3.00cm,right=3.00cm]{geometry}


    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,commath}
    \usepackage{caption}    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    

    \title{\Huge{\textbf{Test}}}
    \author{me}
    \date{}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \centering
                \draw [<->,thick] (0,2.8) node (yaxis) [left] {$t$}
                    |- (2.8,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
                \draw[thick]
                    (0,0) -- (0,-2.8)
                    (0,0) -- (-2.8,0);
                \draw[green, ultra thick] (0,-2.90) -- (0,2.90);
                \draw[dashed] 
                    (0,2.90) -- (0,2.95)
                    (0,-2.90) -- (0,-2.95);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof{figure}{Worldline of a static point-like source}
            \label{fig:static_source}
        \end{minipage}\hspace{2pc}
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw [<->,thick] (0,2.8) node (yaxis) [left] {$t$}
                    |- (2.8,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
                \draw[thick]
                    (0,0) -- (0,-2.8)
                    (0,0) -- (-2.8,0);
                \node[mark size = 3pt, green] at (0,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
                \draw[dashed] 
                    (0,2.90) -- (0,2.95)
                    (0,-2.90) -- (0,-2.95);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof{figure}{Worldline of an instantaneous point-like source}
            \label{fig:inst_source}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    
    \end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]
Please correct me if my understanding is not correct....

Comment: The two caption remain overlapped. The problem is in the ``captionsetup``. If you remove it, the two captions does not overlap anymore.

Comment: @mcp Sorry, I couldn't see the `overlap` of caption, see my edit

Comment: Your example works because you delete `\captionsetup`  in OP MWE (and by this remove wrong caption's settings) and *not*  because you introduce  some space between `minipage`s ...